# Searching for a string in XML

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsstring, httpresponse

I am getting a response from a web service call in XML format. I want to search for the `status` string in the XML response and proceed further depending on its value. How can I do this? The response is below:

```
<META NAME="ColdFusionMXEdition" CONTENT="ColdFusion DevNet Edition - Not for Production Use."><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParticipantService>
    <Response>
        <student_id>10082</student_id>
    </Response>
    <RequestStatus>
        <Code>1</Code>
        <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
        <Message>Valid Credentials.</Message>
    </RequestStatus>
</ParticipantService>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSXmlParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you are checking only for status you can do some string manipulation as follows,

```
NSString *mystring = @"<Response><status>SUCCESS</status> </Response>";
NSString *neededString = nil;
NSScanner *scanner =[NSScanner scannerWithString:mystring];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<status>" intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanString:@"<status>" intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"</status>" intoString:&neededString];
NSLog(@"%@",neededString);
if ([neededString isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]){  //do what you like. }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to XPath in your development libraries ?

If so, you could use (e.g.);

```
if (myDoc.xPath('/RequestStatus[Status = "SUCCESS"]').size() > 0) {  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and chek the "XML Parsing basic" chapter in [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html)

Comment: Is it necessary to definitely Parse the XML response in order to find the status? I am getting the response in nsstring and cant i search for the status string?

Comment: Ah ok..you don't need to parse the xml..use the @Vignesh's solution

Comment: Ya, i have tried using that solution and it works perfectly fine. Anyhow thanks for ur suggestions..